# Will a kitchen with porcelain tiles on the last floor of a house add too much weight?

Tags: construction

My house is more than a 100 years and the kitchen I'm concerned about is on the second floor. I would like to cover my kitchen with porcelain tiles, but I'm thinking that doing so would add too much weight to the house. I mean, I would have to add a lot of cement, wonderboards, and on top of that, the fridge, stove, sink, etc. I'm asking, will the weight be too much for the house?

Comment: Have you tried jumping up and down in the room? Do the plants in the windowsill, or whatever, jiggle? Best option is to get an engineer to look at the room.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help: http://ci.camarillo.ca.us/docs/bs/Weights%20of%20Building%20Materials.pdf - it says 7.7 pounds per square foot for the tiles and the cement backing board. Which isn't that much. If you're putting new cabinets and appliances in, I'd be more worried about those. They weigh a lot more than the flooring, and the weight is concentrated in a smaller space.

Ultimately, the answer will depend on the house.